# Error when using appcmd to delete an application using IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, appcmd

I'm using `appcmd` to script a site I am deploying.  At the start of this I am trying to remove some sites that are automatically installed by a vendor's site.  They need to be removed because they are set up incorrectly putting to a non-existent part of the disk.

The command I am using that is failing is as follows:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd delete app "AccessViaWeb(80)/AVInclude"  

ERROR ( message:Must use exact identifer for APP object with verb DELETE. )
```

I can't figure out the syntax require to avoid this error.

The list of apps on this server can be seen by the `appcmd list apps` command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd list apps  
APP "Default Web Site/" (applicationPool:DefaultAppPool)  
APP "Default Web Site/OPCService" (applicationPool:DefaultAppPool)  
APP "PeopleFinder - 8010/" (applicationPool:PeopleFinder - 8010)  
APP "AccessViaWeb(80)/" (applicationPool:DefaultAppPool)  
APP "AccessViaWeb(80)/AVInclude" (applicationPool:AccessViaWeb)  
APP "AccessViaWeb(80)/AccessViaPrint" (applicationPool:AccessViaPrint)  
APP "AccessViaWeb(80)/SignFunctionService" (applicationPool:SignFunctionService)
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding extra quotes solved this issue for me!

I had an application (Inventory) within another application (Portal):

```
 C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd delete APP "WebSite/Portal/Inventory" /debug
 ERROR ( message:Must use exact identifer for APP object with verb DELETE. )
```

Modifying the command as follows fixed the issue:

```
 appcmd delete APP "Website"/"Portal"/"Inventory"
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help in my case. The app is listed in the output of "appcmd list apps". Moreover I get similar error when I try to delete virtual directory for this app: "Must use exact identifer for VDIR object with verb DELETE". If I remove app from the GUI I can delete virtual directory from command line... HELP! 
I'm using "appcmd DELETE APP /app.name:base/console.io" to delete app and "appcmd DELETE VDIR /vdir.name:base/console.io" to delete virtual directory.

Answer (score 1):

This occur if there are 2 objects with the same ID. A VDIR and a APP. We have solve this only via IIS GUI and not via API.

Answer (score 0):

You sometimes get an error 50 (`ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED`) and the error message

```
ERROR ( message:Must use exact identifer for APP object with verb DELETE. )
```

if the app you want to delete does not exist. The same command will succeed if the app does exist. So you can treat the error codes

- 50 (`ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED`)
- 1168 (`ERROR_NOT_FOUND`)

as success.

This seems to be a bug in `appcmd`, as it doesn't make sense.